# How to decode image with qrcodereader in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I want  to decode image in with npm qr-code-reader but It shows errors, I'm passing base64 image code, image code is write I've checked online it gives result, kindly help me getting out of this problem

```
app.post("/scan-qr", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { qrCode } = req.body;
    // console.log(qrCode);
    const qr = new qrcodeReader();
    qr.callback = async (err, value) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Error scanning QR code" });
      } else {
        // Check if the QR code is valid and matches a generated QR code in the database
        const item = await Item.findOne({ qr: value });
        if (item) {
          res.send({ message: "QR code is valid" });
        } else {
          res.status(401).send({ message: "Invalid QR code" });
        }
      }
    };
    qr.decode(qrCode);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Error scanning  QR code" });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm using postman to give image input,

Comment: You may need to preprocess the image before trying to read the QR code, e.g. to increase the contrast between the light and dark blocks in the code.